# Perl: after parsing text for instances matching regexp and putting them all to massive every entry has extra char

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to get all instances of text matching my regexp from the website (i know regexp are bad for parsing html for some reason, but i all i need is a few lines) except for the same thing preceded with >. So, i basically watch out for XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX, but not the >XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX.

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $perl_page = $ua->get('http://blablabla')->res->dom;

my @results = ($perl_page =~ /[^&gt;][\S]{4}-[\S]{4}-[\S]{4}-[\S]{4}/g);
```

This ignores the >XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX and writes only the instances of XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX, but the entries in massive now contain > themselves! i.e., this script found all XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX and put them into massive with > before each one, so print @codes gives something like >XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX.

Why and how do i fix that? Thanks.

Now, i'm a total noob in perl, so this might sound stupid, but here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is not a typo, `[^&gt;]` doesn't do what you want. You need negative look-behind,

```
/(?<! &gt;) \S{4}-\S{4}-\S{4}-\S{4} /xg
```

Comment: Thanks! What's that /x, tho?

Comment: @Abyrvlag `/x` ignores spaces inside regex (extra spaces improve readability)

Comment: Yep, tested, everything works as intended. Thanks again!